# Mirth Connect - get sent from destination

Tags: mirth

I have 2 destinations in my channel. One is an http sender, the 2nd gets the response from the http sender but I would also like to pull what was sent from that destination also. Can't seem to find the command if one exists to grab that.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your question like this: 
You want to know what was sent from the second destination?

My guess is like you can fetch the output of transformer on the destination end.

Inside tranformer i used `connectorMessage.getEncodedData()` or on the destination we can use the channel map variable `${message.encodedData}` both of them works in the same way it pulls what comes out of your destination.

You can try same `connectorMessage` functionality in the destination transformer or on destination writer to pull the output of what comes from the destination. Hope it works.